# Custom addon not displayed in the addons menu in G1ANT studio

Tags: c#, automation, robotics, rpa, g1ant

I am trying to  create a new addon but the addon is not being displayed in the addons menu in G1ANT Studio. Even other addons installed from the marketplace are also not displayed. I am using the latest version. I have tried running G1ANT studio as administrator. Yet it makes no difference.

Here is the Addon.cs file of my addon:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using G1ANT.Language;

// Please remember to refresh G1ANT.Language.dll in references

namespace G1ANT.Addon.LibreOffice
{
    [Addon(Name = "libreoffice", Tooltip = "Provides commands to automate LibreOffice")]
    [Copyright(Author = "G1ANT LTD", Copyright = "G1ANT LTD", Email = "support@g1ant.com", Website = "www.g1ant.com")]
    [License(Type = "LGPL", ResourceName = "License.txt")]
    [CommandGroup(Name = "calc", Tooltip = "Commands connected with creating editing and generally working on calc")]
    public class LibreOfficeAddon : Language.Addon
    {

        public override void Check()
        {
            base.Check();
            // Check integrity of your Addon
            // Throw exception if this Addon needs something that doesn't exists
        }

        public override void LoadDlls()
        {
            base.LoadDlls();
            // All dlls embeded in resources will be loaded automatically,
            // but you can load here some additional dlls:

            // Assembly.Load("...")
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            // Insert some code here to initialize Addon's objects
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            base.Dispose();
            // Insert some code here which will dispose all unnecessary objects when this Addon will be unloaded
        }
    }
}
```

The addon also references some other DLLs as dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. The G1ANT.Language.dll was in the same directory as the addons, it seems to have been causing the issue.

Comment: The addon should be in which directory ?

Answer (score 3):

There are no errors in your code. Have you ever compiled the HelloWorld example from this tutorial? https://github.com/G1ANT-Robot/G1ANT.Addon.Tutorials/tree/master/G1ANT.Addon.Command.HelloWorld

Remember
1. All dlls in the solution should be marked as "Resource" and will be embeded into your addon
2. The target .NET Framework of your project should be 4.6.1

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. The G1ANT.Language.dll was in the same directory as the addons, it seems to have been causing the issue.